# How does "3x damage" work?

Tags: guild-wars-2

Does the damage from Mind Wrack have diminishing returns?

The tooltip seems to imply that each successive illusion shattered deals less damage. Is this correct, or am I misreading the tooltip, and the shatter does *more* damage per shatter.

[image]

More generally, when a tooltip lists a skill as "2x", does that mean 2 hits at the listed damage, or the total damage, over two hits?

Comment: [I was just watching this video, and it makes it sound as if the skill does have diminishing returns.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jwnDVqZiKOs&feature=player_detailpage)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This needs some testing before i can safely say it works that way. <strike>But as you shatter your clones you do some explosive damage. This would mean that the explossion from 1 illusion would do 85 damage. When you do it with more then 1 clone 3 for example, each one will explode with 150 damage, giving you 450 damage in total.</strike>

After some testing I have found out that it is just the total damage. The mind wrack tooltip shows 1 clone : 37 damage, 2 50 damage and 3 66 damage.

This is one clone, as you can see the explosion does 30 damage.
[image: Mind wrack 1 clone]

This is 2 clones, as you can see the explosion does 21 damage but 2 times which gives 42 damage.
[image: Mind wrack 2 clones]

This is 3 clones, the explosion now only does 19 damage but 3 times which gives 57
[image: Mind wrack 3 clones]

Comment: Where is the zoom!?

Comment: @DavidYell They are huge ass pictures, download, zoom and voila... or you can just trust me when i say the numbers are correct ;)